# Calling a default constuctor for a stack using linked list getting error C2760

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, stack

okay running into a block when it comes to inner class default constructors. in this assignment I have to make a stack utilizing linked list, I got the functions all set I am just having trouble trying to properly set a default constructor for the inner class StackNode at least that is what the compiler is telling me.

```
class StackNode { // this is given in the assignment its not the full .h
    public:
        StackNode(const DataType& nodeData, StackNode* nextPtr)
        {
            dataItem = nodeData;
            next = nextPtr;
        }

        DataType dataItem;
        StackNode* next;
    };

    StackNode* top;
};

// here is my default constructor for the class
template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>::StackLinked(int maxNumber)// <--this part is given inside is what i have done.
{
    top = NULL;
    StackNode::StackNode(const DataType x = NULL; StackNode * y = nullptr)
    {
        this->dataItem = x;
        this->next = y;
    }
//if i remove this i get error C2512 no appropriate default constructor for the StackNode<DataType>::StackNode
}
```

I haven't found a thread yet to help me so I posted this in hopes of finding out what I am missing.

update 1 -
error in output

```
(file dest)\StackLinked.cpp(11,23): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'const', expected ')'
test6.cpp
(file dest)\StackLinked.cpp(11,23): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'const', expected ')'
```

this is the error given when I try to Build my code

Comment: Shouldn't `StackNode` be a template class as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to define the body of the `StackNode` constructor *inside* the body definition of the `StackLinked` constructor.  That will not work.  They need to be defined separately.  But you already have a definition for the `StackNode` constructor inline in the declaration of the `StackNode` class, so there is no need to define a 2nd body for that constructor.

```cpp
template <typename DataType>
class StackLinked
{
private:
    class StackNode {
    public:
        StackNode(const DataType& nodeData, StackNode* nextPtr)
        {
            dataItem = nodeData;
            next = nextPtr;
        }

        DataType dataItem;
        StackNode* next;
    };

    StackNode* top;

public:
    StackLinked(int maxNumber);
};

...

template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>::StackLinked(int maxNumber)
{
    top = NULL;
}
```

Otherwise, don't make the `StackNode` constructor definition be inline, just like you are not for the `StackLinked` constructor:

```cpp
template <typename DataType>
class StackLinked
{
private:
    class StackNode {
    public:
        StackNode(const DataType& nodeData, StackNode* nextPtr);

        DataType dataItem;
        StackNode* next;
    };

    StackNode* top;

public:
    StackLinked(int maxNumber);
};

...

template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>::StackLinked(int maxNumber)
{
    top = NULL;
}

template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>::StackNode::StackNode(const DataType& nodeData, StackNode* nextPtr)
{
    dataItem = nodeData;
    next = nextPtr;
}
```